# TeX4ht generates double footnotes when footnote is defined inside of a csquotes blockquote

Tags: footnotes, tex4ht, csquotes

TeX4ht generates a double footnotes when a footnote is defined inside of a `csquotes` `\blockquote`.

[image: Double Footnot]

Here is a *LaTeX* reproducible example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\section{About Color Science}

The International Commission on Illumination (CIE) defines perceived color as
the~\blockquote{characteristic of visual perception that can be
described by attributes of hue~\footnote{See sub-section~\ref{subsec:terminology}
for the definitions of hue, brightness, lightness, colorfulness, saturation and
chroma.}, brightness (or lightness) and colourfulness (or saturation or
chroma).}

\end{document}
```

My *TeX4ht* stripped config:

```latex
\Preamble{3,charset=utf-8,fn-in,html5,sec-filename,sections+,xhtml}

\EndPreamble
```

And the relevant *HTML* output:

```html
<div class="footnotes"><!--l. 16--><p class="noindent"><span class="footnote-mark"><a href="#fn1x0-bk" id="fn1x0"><sup class="textsuperscript"><span class="ec-lmr-9">1</span></sup></a></span>See sub-section&nbsp;?? for the definitions of hue, brightness, lightness, colorfulness, saturation and
chroma.</p><!--l. 16--><p class="indent"> <span class="footnote-mark"><a href="#fn1x0-bk"><sup class="textsuperscript"><span class="ec-lmr-9">1</span></sup></a></span>See sub-section&nbsp;?? for the definitions of hue, brightness, lightness, colorfulness, saturation
and chroma.</p>                                                                                                          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\blockqoute` command typesets the argument twice, one use is to detect if it contains multiple paragraphs, the second use prints the text. The paragraph detection happens in a `\vbox`, which is then thrown away. The issue is that `tex4ht` detects the footnote in this thrown away box and typesets it, which results in duplicate footnote. An easy fix for this is to just skip the paragraph detection. The downside is, that you will get a different result to regular LaTeX if you use multiple paragraphs inside the `\blockquote` command and only in the case it starts in a middle of a paragraph. I don't know how much often this situation happens, it doesn't seem like a good idea anyway.

Save the following code as `csquotes.4ht`:

```
\long\def\csq@bquote@i#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
\csq@bquote@ii{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}

\Hinput{csquotes}
\endinput
```

The result:

[image]

I will add this file to the tex4ht sources if it works for you.