# producing ODT Arabic edition with apparatus in parnotes via tex4ht: customizing parnote formatting

Tags: footnotes, tex4ht, arabic, parnotes

I would like to convert my edition of Arabic text into ODT format. The edition uses notes that are supposed appear in a smaller font in a paragraph below the text (*not* at the bottom of each page). I would like the footnote hooks to be in Arabic-style numerals ١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠ rather than Roman-style numerals 1234567890. Ideally I would like to be able to select the font (Amiri) to which it will output (current default is Tahoma for the Arabic text).

What I haven't been able to figure out is

1. how to make the footnote hooks Arabic-style
2. how to make the notes paragraph a much smaller font size
3. how to remove a spurious space that comes after the footnote marker in the notes paragraph.

How can I do this?

## MWE

`myfile.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{%
\خ%
    }[2]{%
    \ar{#1}\footnoteA{\ar{#1%
    :
    #2}}%
    }

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Amiri}

%Arabic
\newcommand{\ar}[1]{#1}
\newenvironment{arab}{}{}

% APPARATUS FOR VARIANTS IN ARABIC TEXT
\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}
\SetFootnoteHook{\setRL}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}[alph]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Placing Arabic apparatus at the end of each paragraph
% (WARNING !!! :  currently only works if VARIANT commands only come within `arab` environments)
\usepackage[restart]{parnotes} % package
\renewcommand{\parnotefmt}[1]{\tiny\noindent #1}
\renewcommand{\footnoteA}[1]{\parnote{#1}} % mk app fns parnotes
% \renewcommand*{\parnotecusmarkfmt}[1]{\arabicfont\addfontfeature{Mapping=arabicdigits}\textsuperscript{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\parnotecusmarkfmt}[1]{\arabicfont\addfontfeature{Mapping=arabicdigits}\textsuperscript{#1}}

\let\origArab\arab
\renewenvironment{arab}{\begin{origArab}}{\parnotes{}\end{origArab}} % make arab environment print parnotes at the end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{arab}
\خ{لكن لما}{ڤ؛ إنني كلما: ي}
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with

```
make4ht -uxm draft -f odt -c myconfig.cfg
```

where `myconfig.cfg` is:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ConfigureOO{Footnote}{
<style:style
    style:name="Footnote"
    style:family="paragraph"
    style:parent-style-name="Standard"
    style:class="extra">\Hnewline
  <style:paragraph-properties
             fo:margin-left="0in"
             fo:margin-right="0in"
             fo:text-indent="0.1in"
              style:auto-text-indent="false"/>
  <style:text-properties fo:font-size="83.3333333333333333333333\%"
      style:font-size-asian="83.3333333333333333333333\%"
      style:font-size-complex="83.3333333333333333333333\%" />
</style:style>\Hnewline
<text:notes-configuration text:note-class="footnote"
    text:citation-style-name="Footnote_20_Symbol"
    text:citation-body-style-name="Footnote_20_anchor"
    style:num-format="1" text:start-value="0"
    text:footnotes-position="page"
    text:start-numbering-at="document" />\Hnewline
<style:style style:name="Footnote_20_Symbol"
style:display-name="Footnote Symbol" style:family="text" >\Hnewline
  <style:text-properties style:text-position="super 58\%" />\Hnewline
</style:style>
<style:style style:name="Footnote_20_anchor"
style:display-name="Footnote anchor" style:family="text">
  <style:text-properties style:text-position="super 58\%" />\Hnewline
</style:style>\Hnewline
}

\ConfigureOO{verse}{\Hnewline
<style:style style:name="verse"
             style:family="paragraph"
             style:parent-style-name="Text-body"
             style:next-style-name="Text-body">
<style:paragraph-properties  fo:margin-left="1.499cm"
             fo:margin-right="1cm"
             fo:margin-top="0cm"
             fo:margin-bottom="0cm"
             fo:text-indent="-0.499cm"
             style:auto-text-indent="false">
   <style:tab-stops/>
</style:paragraph-properties >
</style:style>
\Hnewline}

\xeuniuseblock{Greek}
\xeuniuseblock{Arabic}
\makeatletter
\ConfigureEnv{arab}{\@rltrue}{\@rlfalse}{}{}
\Configure{ref}{\Link}{\EndLink}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

## current output

[image]

## desired output

[image]

Comment: there is no configuration for the `manyfoot` package, so the footnotes came as a normal paragraph. I will look at this issue next week, I will be offline next few days

Comment: Okay, after a bit of mucking around, a couple problems: 1: You aren’t using `manyfoot`, because you simply redefine `\footnoteA` to call `\parnote`.

Comment: 2. Because you call `\parnote` instead of `\footnote`, your `\ConfigureOO{footnote}`, etc., never get called.

Comment: 3. Changing the font to Amiri within the document has no effect.  (I believe you can add the `fo:font-family` attribute to the relevant redefinitions in your `.cfg` file.)

Comment: 4. The command to get Arabic-script numerals is incorrect anyway, but also is being ignored by tex4ht. I believe the correct approach is to load `\babel`, `\babelprovide[main, import]{arabic}`, and then use its `\arabicdigits` command.

Comment: 5. However, this does not actually produce a document that compiles correctly with XeLaTeX: tex5ht breaks whenever we load `bidi`.  It seems to be possible to work around this and still get a legible ODT by not loading Bidi.

Comment: 6. There are a number of packages you load that are doing nothing, or actually harmful, such as `fontenc`.

Comment: 7. The footnote mark is not being displayed in an Arabic font, so if you actually set it to the right character, it shows up as an x or not at all.

Comment: 8. I believe you want to examine `parnotes.sty` and use `\NewConfigureOO` and then `\CongifureOO` on the relevant commands there.

Comment: 9. Tex4ht is a total mess. Always make any software you write maintainable, because, God forbid, you might die.

Comment: Oh, and compiling with LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX works with bidi, but you need to have the JDK installed because it runs some class file.

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks for your hard work.

Comment: @Davislor Thank you for all of these observations and for noting all those redundancies. I think they have come about because I was originally using `manyfoot` for my Arabic editions but have changed for the current project to `parnotes`, so rather than redefine all my macros, I redefined `\footnoteA`. Your approach is much cleaner.

Comment: A possible clue (or maybe something to ask in a separate question): with this configuration, when I use a regular `\footnote` in ordinary Roman-style text, it comes out as a duplicate footnote, i.e., one blank note followed immediately by the desired note. This seems to be particular to `tex4ht`, since it doesn't happen when I compile with `pdflatex`/`xelatex`. To judge from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474587/tex4ht-generates-double-footnotes-when-footnote-is-defined-inside-of-a-csquotes), `tex4ht` has done this in other situations as well.

Comment: Oh, and you might try: `\newenvironment{arab}{\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}\begin{autopn}}{\end{autopn}\end{otherlanguage}}`.  The `autopn` environment sets footnotes at the bottom of every paragraph, but it must be wrapped inside another environment.

Comment: Similarly, `\renewcommand{\parnotecusmarkfmt}[1]{\ar{\textsuperscript{\arabicdigits{#1}}}}`

Comment: And `\newcommand{\ar}[1]{{\selectlanguage{arabic}#1}}` (You’ll still need to set RTL in your configuration style, but that will at least let your document compile properly to PDF.)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would define a style (which might be "Footnote") and then make the command, which I believe is `parnotefmt`) insert `<span style=Footnote">` and `</span>` tags into the XML that gets zipped to an ODT.

Comment: I am still slowly working on this. I've fixed few bugs in tex4ht sources, the main issue is now the digits support in XeTeX, it works in LuaTeX. I am still bit busy, so I am not sure when I will post the final solution

Comment: @Davislor Thank you for these various insights. I'm afraid I don't quite know enough to turn that into a solution.

Comment: @michal.h21 Thank you very much for looking into how to do this with XeTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original TeX file doesn't compile correctly with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Here is a modified version that compiles with both of them:

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/495709/2891
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
% \usepackage{xunicode}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\ifdefined\HCode
  \usepackage{babel}
\else
\ifdefined\directlua
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,main]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}
\else
% \usepackage[]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
%\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\fi
\fi

\newcommand{%
\خ%
    }[2]{%
    \ar{#1}\footnoteA{\ar{#1%
    :
    #2}}%
    }

% \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

%Arabic
\newcommand{\ar}[1]{\bgroup\arabicfont#1\egroup}
\newenvironment{arab}{}{}

% APPARATUS FOR VARIANTS IN ARABIC TEXT
\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}
\SetFootnoteHook{\setRL}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}[alph]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Placing Arabic apparatus at the end of each paragraph
% (WARNING !!! :  currently only works if VARIANT commands only come within `arab` environments)
\usepackage[restart]{parnotes} % package
\renewcommand{\parnotefmt}[1]{\tiny\noindent #1}
\renewcommand{\footnoteA}[1]{\parnote{#1}} % mk app fns parnotes
% \renewcommand*{\parnotecusmarkfmt}[1]{\arabicfont\addfontfeature{Mapping=arabicdigits}\textsuperscript{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\parnotecusmarkfmt}[1]{\arabicfont\textsuperscript{\arabicdigits{#1}}}

\let\origArab\arab
\renewenvironment{arab}{\begin{origArab}}{\parnotes{}\end{origArab}} % make arab environment print parnotes at the end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{arab}
\خ{لكن لما}{ڤ؛ إنني كلما: ي}
\end{arab}

\end{document}
```

I've made few changes:

```
% \usepackage{xunicode}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\ifdefined\HCode
  \usepackage{babel}
\else
\ifdefined\directlua
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,main]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}
\else
% \usepackage[]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
%\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\fi
\fi
```

With `tex4ht` only `babel` package is required, with no language definitions, with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX  `babel` or `polyglossia` with options for correct text directions are used.

Another change is to parnotes mark:

```
\renewcommand*{\parnotecusmarkfmt}[1]{\arabicfont\textsuperscript{\arabicdigits{#1}}}
```

The change is that it uses the `\arabicdigits` command instead of relying on the XeLaTeX font mapping mechanism. Thanks to this change, it works with LuaLaTeX.

The configuration file needed only a small change:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,ooffice}
\ConfigureOO{Footnote}{
<style:style
    style:name="Footnote"
    style:family="paragraph"
    style:parent-style-name="Standard"
    style:class="extra">\Hnewline
  <style:paragraph-properties
             fo:margin-left="0in"
             fo:margin-right="0in"
             fo:text-indent="0.1in"
              style:auto-text-indent="false"/>
  <style:text-properties fo:font-size="83.3333333333333333333333\%"
      style:font-size-asian="83.3333333333333333333333\%"
      style:font-size-complex="83.3333333333333333333333\%" />
</style:style>\Hnewline
<text:notes-configuration text:note-class="footnote"
    text:citation-style-name="Footnote_20_Symbol"
    text:citation-body-style-name="Footnote_20_anchor"
    style:num-format="1" text:start-value="0"
    text:footnotes-position="page"
    text:start-numbering-at="document" />\Hnewline
<style:style style:name="Footnote_20_Symbol"
style:display-name="Footnote Symbol" style:family="text" >\Hnewline
  <style:text-properties style:text-position="super 58\%" />\Hnewline
</style:style>
<style:style style:name="Footnote_20_anchor"
style:display-name="Footnote anchor" style:family="text">
  <style:text-properties style:text-position="super 58\%" />\Hnewline
</style:style>\Hnewline
}

\ConfigureOO{verse}{\Hnewline
<style:style style:name="verse"
             style:family="paragraph"
             style:parent-style-name="Text-body"
             style:next-style-name="Text-body">
<style:paragraph-properties  fo:margin-left="1.499cm"
             fo:margin-right="1cm"
             fo:margin-top="0cm"
             fo:margin-bottom="0cm"
             fo:text-indent="-0.499cm"
             style:auto-text-indent="false">
   <style:tab-stops/>
</style:paragraph-properties >
</style:style>
\Hnewline}

\def\loopoverdigits#1{\ifx\relax#1\else%
% Unicode block for Arabic numerals starts at U+0660
% the following special command inserts the XML entity
% for the number, which will be converted to Unicode char
% by tex4ht
\special{t4ht@+&{35}x066#1{59}}x%
\expandafter\loopoverdigits\fi}

\def\arabicdigits#1{\NoFonts\loopoverdigits#1\relax\EndNoFonts}
\ifdefined\xeuniuseblock
\xeuniuseblock{Greek}
\xeuniuseblock{Arabic}
\fi
\makeatletter
\ConfigureEnv{arab}{\@rltrue}{\@rlfalse}{}{}
\Configure{ref}{\Link}{\EndLink}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I've added modified definition for `\arabicdigits`:

```
\def\loopoverdigits#1{\ifx\relax#1\else%
% Unicode block for Arabic numerals starts at U+0660
% the following special command inserts the XML entity
% for the number, which will be converted to Unicode char
% by tex4ht
\special{t4ht@+&{35}x066#1{59}}x%
\expandafter\loopoverdigits\fi}

\def\arabicdigits#1{\NoFonts\loopoverdigits#1\relax\EndNoFonts}
```

It loops over all digits in the argument and prints them as a Unicode entity, using the `\special{t4ht@+&{35}x066#1{59}}x` command. It utilizes the fact, that the Arabic numbers start at `0660` codepoint, so we can just pass the number as the last digit in the codepoint and it will end as a correct Unicode value.

Here is the result in LO:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much! This works perfectly. Is there any way to adjust the customization file slightly so that there is no space after the parnote anchor (as in my original image of the desired output)? Likewise -- though this should probably be a separate question -- I would like to be able to customize the space between each parnote, e.g., to add 5 spaces rather than a single space after each parnote. In any case, thank you again for making this work!

Comment: @AlexRoberts I guess the space after parnote may be caused by a missing `%` at the end of line somewhere in the configurations. Other stuff can be fixed using the OO styles, I think. I will be offline for next week, so I cannot test it more.

Comment: My temporary workaround is to have each parnote add "PARNOTESTART" at the beginning and "PARNOTEEND" at the end. Then I use the word processor's "Find/Replace" to replace a space+ PARNOTESTART with nothing and to replace PARNOTEEND with five spaces. This still saves tons of time!

Comment: @AlexRoberts it still seems like a lot of unnecessary work. I cannot find the source of the space though :(